# tensorflow 2.0 Estimator model using scala/java predict?

Tags: java, scala, tensorflow, apache-spark, tensorflow2.0

I can use python3 tf2.x to predict, but how can i use java to predict?

I tried so many times i found the question maybe is the version of Example.proto, but i'm not sure.. the java code i wrote like this:

```
 val concreteFunction = bundle.function("serving_default")
 val model = sparkEnv.sc.broadcast(concreteFunction)
 val result = sparkEnv.spark.read.parquet(inputPath).map(item => {
      val example = convert2Example(schemaInfo,item)
      val map = new java.util.HashMap[String,Tensor]()
      val b = new String(example.toByteArray)
      val tensor = TString.scalarOf(b)
      map.put("examples",tensor)
      val score = model.value.call(map).get("score")
      score.toString
 }).rdd
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Java? This looks like Kotlin to me.

Comment: this code is scala.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: ”Caused by: org.tensorflow.exceptions.TFInvalidArgumentException: Could not parse example input“